# Ajax call returns "An Error Was Encountered [ 500 ] Unable to load the requested file: default.html" error in pyrocms

Tags: jquery, ajax, pyrocms

**I have a Pyrocms view where I call a controller method using jQuery Ajax, like this**

```
$('#search').click(function(){
var ionum =$('#ionum').val();
var csrf_hash_name = $('input[name=csrf_hash_name]').val();
$.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"admin/ads/filter",
          data:"ionum="+ionum+"&csrf_hash_name="+csrf_hash_name,
          success:function(html){
              alert(html); 
          }
      })
  return false;
});
```

but is not working Every time it returns an error like this

```
An Error Was Encountered [ 500 ]  Unable to load the requested file: default.html
```

My controller method is just echoing a simple string i just want it work after that i will implement my logic controller method is as follows

```
 public function filter(){ 
    $ionum = $this->input->post('ionum');
    echo $ionum;
}
```

Comment: Error 500 means that the server can not run the script in question, most probably due to an error in the code of the script.

Does your script work when you call it directly from the browser? (to test you can substitute POST to GET temporarily)

Comment: what is the name of file which you want to call??

Comment: first block of code if from a js file named as main.js
2nd block is from my admin side controller called as admin.php
wat you are asking i did'nt got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i think its the csrf messing i have written it like that

```
data:"ionum="+ionum+"&csrf_hash_name="+csrf_hash_name,
```

by reordering it like this make it works

```
data:csrf_hash_name="+csrf_hash_name"+"&ionum="+ionum,
```

i wasted my four hours, i was wondering that there is something else that is making problem but its just the ordering issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'url' parameter is not pointing at the right script. You are requesting a relative address of admin/ads/filter which is probably not a location of a PHP script, or something is wrong with your .htaccess rewrite rules.